# How to send a custom object from OnException method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

```
public override void OnException(
         System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);


        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message),
            ReasonPhrase = "Deadly Exception",
        });
    }
```

This is my  filter for Model passed to any asp.net web api.

It works like a charm!

But in my case, what I want is to return custom object (strange need) back to user like:

```
public class ErrorModel
{
   public int StatusCode {get;set;}
   public string ErrorMsg {get;set;}
}
```

What I want to do is (if it is possible):

```
 public override void OnException(
         System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {



        ErrorModel er = new ErrorModel(); //////////// object of class


        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)

         er.StatusCode =200
         er.ErrorMsg="My Custom Msg" 

        // return er object 

    }
```

I want to send the object back from this function but the return type of this method is `void`.

I know `HttpResponseMessage` object can be thrown back, but I want to do it customized way...

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to return that class as JSON.

What you could do is still use the `StringContent` constructor, but pass in a JSON serialized string. You could use Newtonsoft.Json as serialized.

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
{
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject))
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622911/how-to-send-custom-object-with-modelstate-or-expand-modelstate-object

Comment: Done upvoting... If you could help me for next question mentioned in above link...

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what the answer is. I will take a look.