# How to send custom object with modelState, or expand modelState object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

This is a follow-up question from [How to send a custom object from OnException method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30622261)

This is my current code for  `OnActionExecuting`:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
   var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

    if (!modelState.IsValid)
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
             .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
}
```

All my WebAPI requests use this filter which checks whether the model is valid or not.

If not, it will send the `modelState` object (which works fine).

What I want is this: I want to send this `modelState` + my Custom `ErrorMsgModel` shown below in the response:

```
public class ErrorModel
{
    public string StatusMsg { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Let's create an object of the `ErrorModel` class:

```
ErrorModel StatusModel = new ErrorModel();
StatusModel.StatusCode = 500;
StatusModel.StatusMsg = "My Custom Msg";
```

So finally, I want to send this object back. Something like:

```
//return modelState + StatusModel;
```

Or just append the integer `StatusCode` manually to `modelState` object.

How to do that?

Comment: Uh... create a class that aggregates both your modelState and StatusModel and return an instance of that class?